# AttributeError: 'StableDiffusionKDiffusionPipeline' object has no attribute 'sampler'

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, stable-diffusion

installed diffusers version is 0.14.0 im currently getting this error StableDiffusionKDiffusionPipeline' object has no attribute 'sampler'

i tried installing k-diffusion that version is 0.0.14
heres code

```
if not os.path.exists(IMAGE_SAVE_PATH):
    os.mkdir(IMAGE_SAVE_PATH)

def generate_image_name(prompt, ext='.png'):
    from uuid import uuid4
    return f"{IMAGE_SAVE_PATH}/{str(uuid4())}{prompt[:25].replace(' ', '-')}.{ext}"

pipe = StableDiffusionKDiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained(V5_MODEL_PATH, torch_dtype=torch.float16, revision='fp16')
pipe.to("cuda")
with autocast('cuda'):
    image = pipe(prompt).images[0]
image.save(generate_image_name(prompt))
```